# How to enable HTML syntax highlighting in php files

Tags: ide, jetbrains-ide, jetbrains-fleet

How to enable HTML syntax highlighting in PHP files in JetBrains Fleet?

[image: click here for show image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware -- you cannot as this is not currently supported.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/FL-12928 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified with any progress.

Answer (score 0):

The issue should be fixed starting from Fleet 1.15. You may want to update Fleet to the latest version.